# Saving from ai to svg - missing items

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

When saving an .AI file to SVG I am losing some elements.
I have tried `Save As` and `Export` with the same result:

I have grouped it all and ungrouped it all, they are all on the Artboard - there is only one Artboard.

All text is outlined, there are no hidden layers. I have copied and pasted to a new document. When I <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> I can see the outline of everything. Sometimes it will only be one letter of a word missing.

I somehow think I am maybe messing it up when working in isolation mode? (nothing is in isolation mode when "saving as...")

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - but will leave the question up in case someone else has the same problem

Somehow I attached the random items to a guide - so the program figured it was a guide and wouldn't save it

All I had to do was select it - release guides and then delete the guide and it all saved